# Use Emoji in Title?

Tags: database, titles

I need to be able to store emoji in the `title` field of several entries, but whenever the entry is saved the emoji characters are stripped out and replaced with four question marks i.e. `????`.

I imagine this has something to do with character encoding on the database, but is there some way to be able to use emoji in title fields? (specifically for Craft 3; MySQL database)

Comment: What emoji and version of Craft are you using? On Craft 3.6.10, emojis shouldn't even validate when you try to save. Just tested and get "Title cannot contain emoji" validation error.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, I'm still on Craft 3.5.17 as 3.6 introduced some breaking changes that I've yet to look into. But I imagine that means there is no way to get it to work if it now throws an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this isn't possible and is actively not supported as of Craft 3.6.10.